# Is there any possible way to deploy Anagular 2/4 application in Weblogic App Server?

Tags: angular, weblogic

I have developed an app in Angular2 which has to be deployed in the Weblogic App Server. Having a constraint in using Tomcat, is there any way to deploy my app in weblogic?

Comment: After you built the Angular application, just copy the build output to the static web content directory of the server.

Comment: To add to @GünterZöchbauer's comment, we also had to configure a few things.  For example, base-href and deploy-url may have to be set for angular to route correctly.